# Could not uninstall workflow manager for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I tried to uninstall workflow manager for SharePoint 2013 on Server 2012

I removed Workflow Manager for Client from Control Panel.

This message appear after I tried to uninstall Workflow Manager from Control Panel: "This computer is part of a farm. To uninstall, first leave the farm either using 'Leave from Farm' option in Configuration Wizard or Remove-WFHost cmd-let in PowerShell"

I tried both, the error message appear: "The Remove-WFHost was found in the module WorkflowManager, but the module could not be loaded"

Then I tried run "Import-Module WorkflowManager", the error message: "could nott load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Workflow.Cliend. version 1 ....'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall the Workflow Manager Client and then you can remove Manager from the farm.  It's a finicky beast and you need to make sure and follow the directions at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135625/how-to-unconfigure-uninstall-install-and-reconfigure-workflow-manager